# "the first {who / to} call" -- Which is preferred?

Tags: relative-clauses, present-tense, infinitive-clauses

Can I say

> Why should I be the first who call him?

Or should I say

> Why should I be the first to call him?

in present tense, referring to the future?

Answer (score 3):

Either is acceptable, but the version with the infinitival clause (*first to call*) is far more common.

Note that if you *do* use the version with the relative clause, the verb *call* must be in the third person and agree with the referent of *who* in number:

> I will be the first [person] who calls him.
>   We will the first [people] who call him.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-finite clause when the subject is the same as the subject in the main clause. We can understand the time/tense referred to from the context of the main clause. we often use "to-infinite" in non-finite relative clause after ordinal numbers (the first, the second etc.), superlatives (the best, the most beautiful etc.) and after next, last and only.

So, Why should I be the first to call him? is correct.